# "Unexpected list type" exception when invoking ISessionAwareCoreService.GetList()

Tags: tridion

I am invoking the Tridion 2011 SP1 core service via the shipped client assembly. When I attempt to list the contents of a publication, I get an exception.

The code (simplified) looks like this:

```
ItemsFilterData filter = new Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
                     .Client.RepositoryItemsFilterData.RepositoryItemsFilterData();
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { 
    ItemType.Folder, 
    ItemType.StructureGroup 
};
filter.Recursive = false;                        

IEnumerable<IdentifiableObjectData> childItems = core.GetList("tcm:0-15-1", filter);
```

Note: the variable "core" refers to an ISessionAwareCoreService which I can successfully use to call, for example core.GetSystemWideList()

When .GetList is invoked, I get the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
  Message=Unexpected list type: 
     Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.RepositoryItemsFilterData.
```

What are the possible causes of this problem? Can you suggest a good general approach for interpreting this kind of message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't get the direct children of a `Publication` using `GetList`. Instead you should just load the `PublicationData` with a `client.Read` and then access the `RootFolder` and `RootStructureGroup` on that.

```
PublicationData pub = (PublicationData)core.Read("tcm:0-1-1", new ReadOptions());
string rootFolder = pub.RootFolder.IdRef;
string rootSG = pub.RootStructureGroup.IdRef;
```

Alternatively you can call `GetListXml` with your `RepositoryItemsFilterData` and extract the items from the XML yourself.

```
XElement listResult = core.GetListXml(parent.ID, filter);
```